# in c++, .h file include file but does not work

Tags: c++

i declare a string variable in my .h file and assign it in my .cpp file
demo.h:

```
#ifndef DEMO_H
#define DEMO_H
#include <string>
string s;
#endif
```

and demo.cpp:

```
#include "demo.h"
int main(){
  s = "s";
  return 0;
}
```

when i compile demo.cpp it says that

> demo.h: error: ‘string’ does not name a type
>
> demo.cpp:error: ‘s’ was not declared in this scope

but i actually include string in my .h file
i don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: Use the `extern` keyword.

Comment: add this before sring s ;  using namespace std ;

Comment: Thanks, Junhee Shin.

Comment: Do *not* do `using namespace std;`. Use the fully qualified type with `std::string s;`.

Comment: Thanks  G.M.  ,too

Comment: @JunheeShin Especially in a header file do not `using namespace std;`

Comment: especially in header file do not use  string s, either.

Comment: In addition to the other comments: It is very poor practice to declare a variable in a header file. What's the purpose? Read this: [The XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @MichaelWalz `s/declare/define/`, though globals have issues on their own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the namespace, in that case the demo.h should look like:

```
#ifndef DEMO_H
#define DEMO_H
#include <string>
std::string s;
#endif
```

Comment: This will fail if you include `demo.h` in more than one source file. Defining variables in header files is doomed to failure. Not (yet) downvoted.

Comment: Isn't that an other issue? He could use `#pragma once`, if he needs to prevent this.

Comment: No, `#pragma once` is basically the same as your header guard `#ifndef DEMO_H`. Try to include `demo.h` in `source1.cpp` and in `source2.cpp` and link them together, you'll see what happens. Your solution works if you include `demo.h` in one single .cpp file, which makes the `demo.h` header file basically pointless.